# Div with background of 100% scale of image and hoverable button over it with 100% area of div and centered text

Tags: html, css

I have a complicated case. But probably not complicated for you.

I have module called `catsocial` which will contain four social media images with specific dimensions (300x400) in one row which should be 100% of website width. Each 25%, so 4 DIVs will be 100%.

Each of these "images" was placed in module called `catig` for Instagram, `catyt` for YouTube, etc.

Inside social media module I wanted to have personal image which will fill the DIV with `width: 100%` and `height: 100%` of that image. Because I searched a lot here - I found that the only way is to just place an image with specified dimensions inside DIV and then it will fit my DIV completely.

This problem I solved. But I have to place a link `<a href=""></a>` which will be fulfilled with this main DIV (here: `catig`) with also `width: 100%` and `height: 100%` of that DIV but over an image.

Another problem is that this link (inside DIV: `catigbut`) should be displayed on hover only.

The last problem is that text (here: `INSTAGRAM`) should be centerr vertically and horizontally.

I have a code that image displays properly, `catigbut` displays properly with also `width: 100%` and `height: 100%` of that DIV but unfortunately I can't vertically place `INSTAGRAM` text in that div anymore...

```css
.catsocial {
  margin: 50px 0;
}

.catig {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
  background-size: 100% auto !important;
  position: relative;
}

.catigimg {
  width: 100%;
}

.catigbut {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.catigbutlink {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="catsocial">
  <div class="catig">
    <img class="catigimg" src="https://butterflyplace-ma.com/img/Monarch.png" />
    <div class="catigbut">
      <a href="#" class="catigbutlink" target="_blank">
        <h4 class="catigbutlinktitle">INSTAGRAM</h4>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="catig">
    <img class="catigimg" src="https://butterflyplace-ma.com/img/Monarch.png" />
    <div class="catigbut">
      <a href="#" class="catigbutlink" target="_blank">
        <h4 class="catigbutlinktitle">INSTAGRAM</h4>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I will be so thankful for help - how to make this text centered vertically.
But if there is any bug inside code, please let me know, because I am thinking about it over 3 days and can't find a solution...

[here is a screenshow I was asked for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDFHr.jpg)

Comment: I think a screenshot of your design would help understand what you're trying to achieve. I was lost at the 4th paragraph...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set position: absolute of **`.catigbutlink`** and try to use **`transform`** for vertical align center. And for hover set **`opacity:0`** default and set **`opacity:1`** on hover

```css
body {
  font: 13px Verdana;
}

.catsocial {
  margin: 50px 0;
}

.catig {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
  background-size: 100% auto !important;
  position: relative;
}

.catigimg {
  width: 100%;
}

.catigbut {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.catigbutlink {
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #ff000069;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
}

.catig:hover .catigbut {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.catigbutlink h4 {
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="catsocial">
  <div class="catig">
    <img class="catigimg" src="https://butterflyplace-ma.com/img/Monarch.png" />
    <div class="catigbut">
      <a href="#" class="catigbutlink" target="_blank">
        <h4 class="catigbutlinktitle">INSTAGRAM</h4>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="catig">
    <img class="catigimg" src="https://butterflyplace-ma.com/img/Monarch.png" />
    <div class="catigbut">
      <a href="#" class="catigbutlink" target="_blank">
        <h4 class="catigbutlinktitle">INSTAGRAM</h4>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope this will help you!

Comment: YES, This is what makes my problem *almost* solved. Question is - that I have a clickable right now only a text when it appear. Is it possible to make an area of click to be inside whole DIV...

Comment: @Krupers then change your click selector to the div class. Can you share your click event code, it will be easy to resolve your issue

Comment: I could do it if I have it... I mean I wanted to use only HTML+CSS to make width and height of that ANCHOR HREF to be 100%, then when I hover over div with image, ANCHOR appear and no matter I will have my cursor on a text or not - link will be everywhere. This what I tried to do.

Comment: YAS! YAS! YASSS!! You are my MASTER! Thank you so much *hugging* Oh gosh... I tried so long and that was such a simple! I just changed my colors and added a border to text but this is what I wanted to see. Thank you once again!!!

Comment: Glad! It helped you:)

Answer (score 0):

I took out some of your code.

I did a flex-box design for easy centering. There is a very good tutorial on flex-box [here.](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) This centers (vert. and horiz.) the Instagram link. I had to add a div to center the anchor tag. Let me know if there is something else you wanted.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
 <head>
  <style>
   .catsocial {
     width: 100%;
     height: 300px; //you mentioned each picture is 300 height
     margin: 50px 0;
   }

   .catig {
     width: 25%;
     height: 100%;
     background-image: url('https://butterflyplace-ma.com/img/Monarch.png');
     background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
     background-size: 100% 100% !important;
   }

   .catigbut {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     display: flex; /*flex-box design for easy centering*/
     justify-content: center; /*center horizontally*/
     align-items: center; /*center vertically*/
   }
  </style>
 </head>

 <body>
  <div class="catsocial">
   <div class="catig">
    <div class="catigbut">
     <div class="Added to make display:flex work">
      <a href="#" class="catigbutlink" target="_blank">
       <h4 class="catigbutlinktitle">INSTAGRAM</h4>
      </a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, this is awesome! WOW... but - have a question. Flex-Box will be compatible with all browsers and mobile devices?

Comment: In my experience, yes. I have not yet had an issue with flex-box in browsers.